# Treetagger koRpus package error

Tags: r, text, analysis, korpus

I am trying to use the Treetag function in the koRpus package. 
The code I have used is

```
tagged.text <-treetag("C:/Rec_By_Others.txt",treetagger="manual",lang="en",TT.options=list(path="C:\\Program Files\\TreeTagger", preset="en"))
```

But I keep encountering with the following error.

```
Error in matrix(unlist(strsplit(tagged.text, "\t")), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

What do I do ?

Comment: I have this problem as well and can't find a solution for it. Very frustrating! How do we get in touch with the package's author? Perhaps s/he can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me, but I had the same error message. I could not find any solution for this problem until today. I finally found that I had a problem with the PERL installation, so I reinstalled a new version of PERL. Then, I checked if TreeTagger worked properly by applying the README TreeTagger instruction, that is:

### Installation

1. Install a Perl interpreter (if you have not already installed one).    You can download a Perl interpreter for Windows for free at    http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/
2. Extract the zip file (if it was not extracted yet) and move the    TreeTagger directory to the root directory of drive C:.
3. Download the parameter files for the languages you need, decompress    them (e.g. using Winzip or 7zip) and move them to the subdirectory TreeTagger/lib.    Rename the parameter files to -utf8.par   Example: Rename french-par-linux-3.2-utf8.bin to french-utf8.par    Non-UTF8 parameter files are not supported anymore.
4. Add the path C:\TreeTagger\bin to the PATH environment    variable. The necessary steps differ from one Windows version to the other.
5. Open a command prompt window and type the command    set PATH=C:\TreeTagger\bin;%PATH%
6. Go to the directory C:\TreeTagger    cd c:\TreeTagger
7. Now you can test the tagger, e.g. by analyzing this file with the command    tag-english INSTALL.txt If you install the TreeTagger in a different directory, you have to modify the first path in the batch files tag-*.bat using an editor such as Wordpad.

Note also that:
**if you install the TreeTagger in a different directory, you have to
modify the first path in the batch files tag-*.bat using an editor
such as Wordpad.***

I hope this help.